# Select something and change the text of a TextBox -- #name? error

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2003

For some sort of reason, which I can't seem to spot, this fails and I get a #Name? error.  When I tried to do this, I use pretty much the same code in another place in my form; the only difference is the "cbo" and the names of my txt and alike.

```
Private Sub cboVarenummer_AfterUpdate()
  Dim LSQLVareNavn  As String
    LSQLVareNavn = "select Varenavn from VARENUMMER where VARENUMMER.Varenummer = '" & cboVarenummer & "'"
    txtVarenavn.ControlSource = LSQLVareNavn
End Sub
```

Can anyone spot my error?

What I wish the code would do is when I `Select` something in my cboVarenummer, the TextBox txtVarenavn changes its text to what the sql statement returns.

Comment: What's the rowsource of the original dropdown box? It looks like you're trying to look up data and store it when it's dependent on the data in another field. Ypu may be able to get the piece of data you want from a column of the combo box. Or you should maybe have a join to the table you're getting this from in the underlying RecordSource of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**what i wish the code would do is when i Select something in my cboVarenummer, the my txtbox txtVarenavn changes its text to what the sql statement returns**

In that case, I think you should be changing txtVarenavn's .Value property rather than its .ControlSource property.

Also use the [DLookup()](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208786) function to retrieve the value you want to store in txtVarenavn.Value

```
Private Sub cboVarenummer_AfterUpdate()
    'Dim LSQLVareNavn  As String '
    Dim strWhere As String
    'LSQLVareNavn = "select Varenavn from VARENUMMER where VARENUMMER.Varenummer = '" & cboVarenummer & "'" '
    'txtVarenavn.ControlSource = LSQLVareNavn '
    strWhere = "Varenummer = '" & Me!cboVarenummer & "'"
    Me!txtVarenavn = DLookup("Varenummer", "Varenummerf", strWhere)
End Sub
```

Compare the DLookup expression to your previous SELECT statement.  You can see how the field name, table name, and WHERE clause correspond between the two.  Think of DLookup as a simple SELECT ... it returns only a single value rather than a recordset ... but that's exactly what you need here.

I also changed the table name to Varenummerf, as you listed in your comment to @Ben.  VARENUMMER as the table and Varenummer as the field name might not confuse Access' database engine, but it makes me uneasy.  :-)

Comment: i think ill stick with DLookup :P it works and i get the result i want.. Thanks for the help :P

Answer (score 0):

Did you not want cboVarenummer.SelectedValue.Tostring (Or cboVarenummer.SelectedItem.Tostring dependant on how you populated the combo box) in the SQL Query?

Comment: well im not the origanl creator, but the raw source is this: SELECT DISTINCTROW Varenummerf.Varenummer, Varenummerf.Varenavn, Varenummerf.Varenavn2 FROM Varenummerf;  And it can't find the SelectedItem nor value, only something called SelItem...

Comment: I just hit mé This is bc i use access 2003, i Got both value and text, but non of Them seems to work? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You where statement as it stands is wrong, you need to build it up like this: select Varenavn from VARENUMMER where VARENUMMER.Varenummer = '" & cboVarenummer.SelectedItem & "'". The way you have it at the moment will not put the value of combo box in the statement, but the type. This is assuming that you are in fact using vb.net.

Comment: Hey ben, im act. not really sure what im using, its the lang that comes with access 2003, and i think .net is from 2000, but might be my memory that fails me ^^ anyway, i found another solution but thanks anyway :P